# How to draw or create a Horizontal Divider in a Python FMX GUI App?

Tags: python, user-interface, firemonkey, horizontal-line

How do I create a Horizontal Divider Line as can be seen in the screenshot above the buttons:

[image: UI with three buttons, divider line, and two radio buttons]

How can this be accomplished in an [FMX GUI App for Python](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiFMX4Python)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a `Line` component that you can create. I've created one here:

```
self.myLine = Line(self)
self.myLine.Parent = self
self.myLine.Align = "Center"
self.myLine.Position.X = 100
self.myLine.Position.Y = 100
self.myLine.Width = 1000
self.myLine.Height = 5
self.myLine.LineType = "Top"
```

And here's how it looks on a `Form`:

[image: Python GUI App with Horizontal Line]

You can obviously move and place it where you want it as well as choose the size and other properties.